# Jhipster "com.github.erslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.11.3:npm" goal failed

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to run a "mvn clean package". I've got an error that saying  it cannot run "[my_project_path]\target\node\node.exe" because I need some permissions that I don't have.

[jHipster error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvtKG.png)

I have a Node installation elsewhere on the disk and I want to know if it possible to setup the Node.exe used.

Comment: Not sure your analysis is correct, I don't see any evidence that it's a file permission problem. The frontend-maven-plugin installs its own version of node and npm as specified in pom.xml into a sub directory of your build directory, so there should not be any permission issue or you won't be able to build anything. Are you running mvn or mvnw (as documented)? Have you same issue if you run goals separately `mvnw clean` and `mwnw package`?

Comment: Might be related to windows somehow? Can you check if the node.exe in target is e.g. a non zero byte file or so?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this?

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Try to update your packages version.

1. `npm install -g npm-check-updates`  (to check the current nd update versions of all)
2. `ncu -u` (to update)
3. `npm install`